# Can't get ParseObject values

Tags: android, parse-platform

Followed the online Parse docs to get the value but Android Studio won't recognize the `getInt` method & says - `Cannot resolve method 'getInt(java.lang.String)`

Shouldn't I be able to access the object inside the done callback? Currently the line is commented out because I can't build the project due to the error?

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Stats");
query.whereEqualTo("Name", rstr);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> stats, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + stats.size() + " scores");
                //int score = stats.getInt("errors");
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the `ParseObject` from the `stats` variable first, like below

```
ParseObject object = (ParseObject) stats.get(position);
int score = object.getInt("errors");
```

Answer (score 0):

`stats` is not a `ParseObject`, it's a `List<ParseObject>`.  You need to get the objects out of the list.